# Understand oauth2 on resource server side

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a little question because I am trying to understand the notion of authentication server. I saw lot of diagram explaining for example oauth. But there is something I do not understand.
It is the validation of the token to let access to the resource server.

I made a little diagram to explain where is my question.

Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Have a nice day

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1. Check the authorization server to see if the token is valid.
2. Issue self-validating tokens (using cryptographic techniques) such that the resource server can quickly determine the validity of the token.

I believe that number 2 is far more common, because it's capable of much better performance.

[Here](http://nimbusds.com/blog/implementing-oauth-2-0-access-tokens/) is a good article laying out the pros and cons of the two approaches. Their performance summary:

> The self-contained + RSA signed access tokens emerge as the clear winner from this benchmark, by a factor of at least ten.

Comment: Thx I will have a look :)

Comment: Nice link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Resource Server should be able to accept (decrypt and validate expiration, roles, ...) the access tokens issued by the Authorization Server and respond with the protected resource if the the access token is valid.

Check [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/) link.

Comment: Thx for your answer